# Mean-Stack (getting my collections to display)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, mean

Currently working on a mean stack project i have a products collection inside of my mongodb. I was wondering how i would go about getting that products collections raw data and having it display on my (localhost:4200/products) page? Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated i’m still learning.

Comment: HI, take a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ... there you have tagged this question with Node JS and express... there are countless internet articles which go over your requirement; if you hit an obstacle, you can always come back to ask here.

Comment: Still having trouble even after reviewing other similar questions

Comment: if you share minimal code and error you're getting, you'll get more help...